# What coefficient could I use to calculate the relative difficulty of a test in relation to others using only mean and population standard deviation?

Tags: estimation, variance, psychometrics

I have a series of tests, all of them of different difficulty, and from each of them I get an average score and a population standard deviation; e.g:

```
86.94%  16.27%  
84.17%   6.52%  
99.55%   1.19%
81.70%   9.61%  
99.82%   0.34%
```

Now, clearly the last test, that has an average of 99.82% and a standard deviation of 0.34% is a lot easier than the one with a mean of 81.7% and a standard deviation of 9.61% (supposing of course the variations of results are effect of the difficulty and not of the population that took the test).

What I'm trying to figure out is a coefficient that uses only that data to get a number that properly reflects how much more difficult was one test than the others.
I hope you can help.

btw: sorry for the wrong tag, I'm not sure which would have been a good fit.

Comment: In order to have a measure of 'how much more difficult' a test is, you'd have to define what, exactly, 'difficulty' is measured by. It would be easy to compute average differences in *score*, but how score differences map to 'difficulty differences' would require us to define what we actually mean (in an operational sense) by difficulty.

Comment: Much of test theory is concerned with just this type of question. Two broad areas are classical test theory and item response theory. But, given just the data you have, I think you're stuck with using what you've already got.

Comment: Sorry, I only have a basic statistics knowledge. @PeterFlom I also have individual scores from each person for each test in case that's helpful. What does exactly mean being stuck with what I have? That there's no way of measuring diff? I wouldn't know exactly how to define "difficulty." Anyway, I'll look into the classical test theory WP article-

Comment: You could look at difference in percentages, for instance.

Comment: One possibility might be to consider the scores as "proportions correct" and consider odds ratios (or their logarithm) as a measure of relative difficulty, but neither the questions will be equally hard nor the test-takers will generally have equal ability; without the individual-question-level data you couldn't tease out the underlying odds ratios.

Comment: It seems you are a bit hooped here.  If they are the same candidates, then there is a huge mismatch between candidate ability and the assessment instrument (e.g., a grade 9 math test being given to first year honors math students). Also, test scores (raw scores) are not really interval measures, they are ordinal.  You may not be truly able to compare them in classical test terms.  If you ran the data through a Rasch model or IRT model, you could place them on the same metric and compare them. You have just scratched a very large field!